# Regex expression for float and ratio expression after a comparison operator

Tags: c#, regex

I need validate some input that have the following structure:

```
[<|>|<=|>=](optional) [integer value| float value| ratio value](required)
```

For example these values are allowed, `=6, >=8.56, <8/4, 8.56`.

I want do this whit Regex `@"^?<operator>(<|>|<=|>=)?(([\d]+)|([\d]+(.|/)[\d]+))$"` is not working.

Comment: You forgot at least commas in the regex.

Comment: Check if [`^(?<op><=|>=|[<>=])?(?<val>\d+(?:[./]\d+)?)(?:,\s*(?<op><=|>=|[<>])?(?<val>\d+(?:[./]\d+)))*$`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e(%3f%3cop%3e%3c%3d%7c%3e%3d%7c%5b%3c%3e%3d%5d)%3f(%3f%3cval%3e%5cd%2b(%3f%3a%5b.%2f%5d%5cd%2b)%3f)(%3f%3a%2c%5cs*(%3f%3cop%3e%3c%3d%7c%3e%3d%7c%5b%3c%3e%5d)%3f(%3f%3cval%3e%5cd%2b(%3f%3a%5b.%2f%5d%5cd%2b)))*%24&i=%3d6%2c+%3e%3d8.56%2c+%3c8%2f4%2c+8.56) works for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex that will *validate* the strings like your example string:

```
@"^(?<op><=|>=|[<>=])?(?<val>\d+(?:[./]\d+)?)(?:,\s*(?<op><=|>=|[<>])?(?<val>\d+‌​(?:[./]\d+)))*$"
```

See [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%3F%3Cop%3E%3C%3D%7C%3E%3D%7C%5B%3C%3E%3D%5D)%3F(%3F%3Cval%3E%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5B.%2F%5D%5Cd%2B)%3F)(%3F%3A%2C%5Cs%2A(%3F%3Cop%3E%3C%3D%7C%3E%3D%7C%5B%3C%3E%5D)%3F(%3F%3Cval%3E%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5B.%2F%5D%5Cd%2B)))%2A%24&i=%3D6%2C%20%3E%3D8.56%2C%20%3C8%2F4%2C%208.56)

Note that in .NET, we can use the same group name multiple times and all the captures are available through a [`CaptureCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.capturecollection(v=vs.110).aspx) (per each group).

In order to validate the whole input containing comma+space separated `<operator>+<number/ratio>` strings, you need to repeat the subpattern.

*Explanation*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?<op><=|>=|[<>=])?` - 1 or 0 occurrence of `<=` or `>=` or `<`, `>` or `=`
- `(?<val>\d+(?:[./]\d+)?)` - 1 or more digits optionally followed by a dot or a `/` and 1 or more digits
- `(?:,\s*(?<op><=|>=|[<>])?(?<val>\d+‌​(?:[./]\d+)))*` - 0 or more sequences of...

  - `,\s*` - a comma followed by 0 or more whitespace
  - `(?<op><=|>=|[<>])?(?<val>\d+‌​(?:[./]\d+)` - the subpattern used at the beginning of the pattern
- `$` - end of string